# Creating simple p5.js canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas, p5.js

I'm trying to create the most basic example of p5.js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  function setup() {
    createCanvas(500, 500);
    background(200);
  }
});
```

This doesn't work. Canvas was not created at all and there is no error in the console.

But this solution works:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var sketch = function(p) {
    p.setup = function () {
      p.createCanvas(640, 480);
      p.background(200);
    };
  };
  new p5(sketch);
});
```

I've seen it here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41126499/2986401

However, the first example is the recommended way. Why it is not working? How can I get it at work? (I have a low level of JS) Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should **not** call the `setup()` function yourself. The P5.js library calls it for you. Calling it yourself short-circuits all the cool stuff that P5.js does, and it's why you're getting a "createCanvas is not defined" error.

Basically, by default (aka in global mode), P5.js looks for top-level functions like `setup()` and `draw()` that it calls automatically for you after the library is loaded. That's why your first example doesn't work: the `setup()` function is buried inside an anonymous function that you're passing into JQuery's `ready()` function.

In other words, you do **not** want to use `onload()` or JQuery's `ready()` functions with P5.js. You want to let P5.js automatically call those functions when the library is loaded.

Here's a simple example that includes the required HTML to give you a better idea of what's going on:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>P5.js Example</title>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.5.14/p5.js"></script>
        <script>
            function setup(){
                createCanvas(500, 500);
                background(64);
            }

            function draw(){
                fill(255);
                ellipse(mouseX, mouseY, 20, 20);
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

This code defines top-level `setup()` and `draw()` functions. When the P5.js library is loaded, it automatically calls these functions.

If you try to call `setup()` yourself, you'll do so before P5.js is loaded, which is why the `createCanvas()` function is not defined.

Your second example is using **instance mode**, which puts the `setup()` and `draw()` function inside an object that P5.js uses for calling functions. See [here](https://github.com/processing/p5.js/wiki/Global-and-instance-mode) for more info. But even with instance mode, you probably still wouldn't need to use the `onload()` or JQuery's `ready()` function.

Shameless self-promotion: I've written a tutorial on how P5.js works available [here](http://happycoding.io/tutorials/p5js/hello-world).

Comment: Yes! Thank you very much. Lately I was learning about instance and global modes, but this explanation is really usefull.

Comment: I understand now the problem. Anyway, it is not solved yet because my setup function is in the context of Sage (WordPress starter theme), and all JS are enveloped into anonymous function. This is the context of JS in Sage: https://github.com/roots/sage/blob/8.5.3/assets/scripts/main.js I undestand that is another question, related to Sage. I tried there: https://discourse.roots.io/t/level-up-javascript-function-to-root-of-scope/10964

Comment: @aitor Yep, please ask any follow-up questions in their own posts. But why don't you just use instance mode if that works for you? Nothing says that you should use global mode. Instance mode is there for a reason. If it solves your problem, just use that.

Comment: Is just for learning purposes: with instantiation, all code is more complex. But, I'll try that way ;)